# Navigation Menu buttons clickable in Navigation Drawer

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I've got to this point of creating navigation drawer where I don't know how to make the buttons clickable from the drawer.

My `MainActivity`:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mToggle;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout);
        mToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,R.string.open, R.string.close);

        mDrawerLayout.addDrawerListener(mToggle);
        mToggle.syncState();

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        if(mToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)){

            return true;
        }
        else{
            switch (item.getItemId()){
                case R.id.nav_menu:
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Menu!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return true;
                case R.id.nav_setings:
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Settings!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return true;
            }
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Please note that switch statement in `onOptionsItemSelected` doesn't work.

My menu xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:id="@+id/nav_menu"
          android:title="My Account"/>
    <item android:id="@+id/nav_setings"
          android:title="Settings"/>
    <item android:id="@+id/nav_logout"
          android:title="Log Out"/>

</menu>
```

So, my question is how to make those items from the drawer clickable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you also have a [`NavigationView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/NavigationView.html) inside your `DrawerLayout`, you just have to add an [`OnNavigationItemSelectedListener`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener.html):

```
NavigationView navigation = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation);

navigation.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        switch(item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.nav_menu:
                // Handle menu click
                return true;
            case R.id.nav_settings:
                // Handle settings click
                return true;
            case R.id.nav_logout:
                // Handle logout click
                return true;
            default:
                return false;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks for your help, i've added this code and look like it is working. Only think it that Android Studio warning it might produce NUllPointerException - how to solve this?

Comment: @cheeroke What line is the warning appearing on?

Comment: it is highliting whole block of `navigation.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {}`

Comment: @cheeroke Huh, that is strange, I don't get the same warning. Adding a null check around the call to `setNavigationItemSelectedListener()` wouldn't hurt: `if(navigation != null) { … }`. Though it shouldn't be necessary considering you just set the `navigation` object in the previous line.

Comment: hmm, adding `@NonNull` did not help but wrapping around in `if(navigation != null) { … }` works. appreciate your help - thank you.